# Javascript: filling inputs with text without overwriting the text that is already there

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, autofill

I am trying to create a button that adds text to input when clicked, but instead of adding text it overwrites the text that's already typed in there. I need help.
 Here's the code:

```html
<script>
  function autoFill() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0]

    input.value = "text overwrites instead of adding";
  }
</script>

<input type="input"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
```

Comment: just a sidenote, if you know that you will always only ever want the first input element, consider using `document.querySelector('input')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should be as simple as:

`input.value += "text overwrites instead of adding";`

The **+=** operator adds something to a variable while **=** assigns a new value.

Picture this:

```
var a=8;
a+=4;
console.log(a);
```

traces 12

If we do it like this:

```
var a=8;
a=4;
console.log(a);
```

traces 4

Comment: just consider adding a space after the input value,but everything seems fine even without it

Comment: You're surely ain't dumb - such things can happen. Glad I could help!

Comment: Wait a minute... I want it to add text to the current input while the cursor is blinking. It only applies to the first input when there are multiple inputs are on the page.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't really understand that. Can you specify your question?

Comment: Ah gotcha! Well those are two separate things not really related to the initial problem. Maybe you should raise a new question so this one doesn't get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the input that exists - append the new content to it and  then pass the new value back to the input.

```js
function autoFill() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
    var val = input.value;
    var newContent = "new content";
    input.value = val + " " +  newContent;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Sample text">
<button type="button" onclick="autoFill()">fill it!</button>
```